# Split branch name regex

Tags: regex

What regex could I use if I wanted to match `bar-100` from `foo/bar-100-baz`. The original string could be longer with more hyphens.

Total regex beginner don't really have a start..

`\/([^-]+)` matches `bar` but I want to match the second hyphen somehow.

Comment: You may use: `\/([^-]+-[^-]+)`

Comment: _"The original string could be longer with more hyphens"_ What's your desired output in case of more hyphens?

Comment: Where do you use the regex? Show the code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a full-match might be desired, then

```
(?<=/)[a-z]+-\d+
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/WUpiCY/1/)

or,

```
[a-z]+-\d+(?=-)
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Rp3J3B/1/)

or,

```
[^/]+(?=-)
```

[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/dKdZ4W/1/)

might also work OK.

Comment: This is what I wanted! Thank you for the quick response.